# editable text and storing that text in android

Tags: java, android

I am beginner to android..i created four images and below each image i added text
for that image i added renaming option by onlong click of text..for storing renamed 
text i am using shared prefrences in my fragment..if i go next fragment and if i
come back my fragment edited text is not displaying..its displaying what i added text in layout..can anyone help me....below is my code

```
     public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
     @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ac_listview, container, false);

    final TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView8);

          ImageView image1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);


    image1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View _view) {
            int viewId = _view.getId();
            FragmentTransaction ft;
            switch (viewId) {
                case R.id.imageView3:
                    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                    ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                    NEXTFRAGMENT nextFragment = new NEXTFragment();

                   ft.replace(R.id.frame_content, nextFragment);
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft.commit();
                    break;

            }


        }
    });

    text1.setText("green");

    text1.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) getActivity()).getLayoutInflater();

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.name_edit, null);
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

            alertDialogBuilder.setView(view);

            final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            Button done = (Button) View.findViewById(R.id.edit_done);
            final TextView new1 = (TextView) View.findViewById(R.id.name);

            done.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                   String str = new1.getText().toString();

                    if(str.equals(""))
                    {
                        new1.setError(Constants.NOT_EMPTY);

                    }
                    else{
                        text1.setText(str);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = MAINActivity._sharedPreferences.edit();
                        editor.putString("Str", str);
                       editor.commit();
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                }

            });
            alertDialog.show();

            return true;

        }


    });
```

Comment: You should set text on your TextView in onCreateView by getting from SharedPreferences. Follow @Anjali answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your onCreateView of fragment write following code it will work:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String imgUpdateName = prefs.getString("Str", "");
text1.setText(imgUpdateName);
```

so your onCreateView will be :

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ac_listview, container, false);

    final TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView8);

          ImageView image1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
 SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String imgUpdateName = prefs.getString("Str", "");
    text1.setText(imgUpdateName);

.......

Your remaining fragment code.
```

Comment: anjali i tried same problem i dont know what mistake i did...can you send full code

Answer (score 0):

Here you go! Add this on your fragment code!

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint ( boolean isVisibleToUser){
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            yourTextView.setText(""+yourSharedPrefObject.getString("Str",""));
        }
    }
```